# Register generics with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I need to register a few generic interfaces with Autofac.

With Structure Map I was using the following:

```
 Scan(x => {
    x.AssemblyContainingType<MvcApplication>();
    x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandler<>));
    x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IOrderHandler<,>));
    x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IAsyncEventHandler<>));
    x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IAsyncOrderHandler<,>));
    x.WithDefaultConventions();
  });
```

What is the best way to register these generics in Autofac?

I would like to specify the four interfaces ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AsCloseTypesOf` method :

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandler<,>))
```